# Swift 2 : error when try to find with indexOf

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

in global variable part i have this declaration

```
var friends:NSArray = NSMutableArray() // because i use them to share data into two segues
```

this is the starting code for my tableView function :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    let user:PFUser = allUsers.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFUser

    if(isFriend(user)) {
        // remove friend

        // 1) Remove the Checkmark
        cell.accessoryType = .None

        // 2) Remove from Array list of friends

        for friend in self.friends {
            if friend.objectId == user.objectId {
                if let foundIndex = friends.indexOf(friend) {

                    //remove the item at the found index
                    self.friends!.removeAtIndex(foundIndex)
                }
            }
        }

        // 3) Remove from backend

    }
...
}
```

i try to find index of tapped friend in friends list to Add or Delete friend into array "friends" with :

```
if let foundIndex = friends.indexOf(friend)
```

I have a red alert with this line : Value of type NSArray has no member indexOF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A NSArray or NSMutableArray isn't the same thing as a Swift native array (which has the `indexOf` functionality).

Try doing:

```
let foundIndex = friends.indexOfObject(friend)
if foundIndex != NSNotFound {
   // do something with the found index...
}
```

Comment: when i use your code  i have an error with line `code` self.friends!.removeAtIndex(foundIndex) `code` error is : Value of type NSArray has no member removeAtIndex

Comment: That's because NSArray is not mutable (and doesn't have a `removeAtIndex` method).  But a mutable array does.  Change this line: `var friends:NSArray = NSMutableArray()` into `var friends:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()` or `var friends = NSMutableArray()`.  `let friends = NSMutableArray()` might even work as well since you're declaring a NSMutableArray and not changing that property afterwards (you're only changing the contents of the mutable array).

Comment: i change the var line with `var friends:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()` and now i have the same error with NSMutableArray has not member removeAtIndex...

Comment: YEAH ! i change `self.friends.removeAtIndex(foundIndex)` for  `self.friends.removeObjectAtIndex(foundIndex)` and now is working ! Thank you for your help !

Comment: Of course, there remains the question of why you're using `NSArray` and not a Swift array to begin with...

Answer (score 2):

You can make your life much easier if you use native `Array` type

```
var friends = [PFUser]()
```

then the loop to remove the item can be simplified

```
for (index, friend) in friends.enumerate() {
  if friend.objectId == user.objectId {
    //remove the item at the found index
    friends.removeAtIndex(index)
    break
  }
}
```

or even

```
if let index = friends.indexOf({$0.objectId == user.objectId}) {
   friends.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var anIndex: Int = myArray.indexOfObject(num)
```

from [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:)

Comment: Ok I need to know the numeric index to use indexOfObject, it is possible to find "friend" into "friends" array with "friend" parameter ?

Comment: From apple docs:
Declaration
SWIFT
func indexOfObject(_ anObject: AnyObject) -> Int

you dont need to know numeric index.

Answer (score 1):

`-indexOf` is for a Swift type array. 
If you're planning to use `NSMutableArray`, use `-indexOfObject()`

so your `friends` array should be listed as:

```
var friends: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

for friend in self.friends {
    if friend.objectId == user.objectId {
        if let foundIndex = friends.indexOfObject(friend) {

            //remove the item at the found index
            self.friends!.removeAtIndex(foundIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you don't really have to use NSMutableArray(). You can easily just use a swift array by doing something like this:

```
var friends: [PFUser] = [] // this is mutable because it's var
```

If you need to add objects into this array, you can do so with `-append`.
Then you'll be able to use the method `-indexOf` that you were using.

Comment: whit this code i have an error : Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'int' for line `if let foundIndex = friends.indexOfObject(friend) {  `